# Getting Illegal character in query when doing a conditional GET with multiple parameters

Tags: karate

Code:

Feature: GET API headers feature

Scenario: pass GetWatchList with headers

```
Given header x-apisignatures = '543aba07839'
And header ssotoken = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWUiOiJjYTM4MDAzZS0wYThiLTQ3YjktOWFjNS00YzMyN2MwNTUyMGYiLCJ1c2VyVHlwZSI6IlJJTHBlcnNvbiIsImF1dGhMZXZlbCI6IjIwIiwiZGV2aWNlSWQiOiJlZWIxOGRlOGRiNjE3MDg4MjViNTdjNGU5NDg1ZmFjYTU1MGE1OTBkY2Y1MjIzNzkyYzUwYjVhZWRjZGI5ZmUxNDQxZTFiMzhmZWI2NDFhZmUwNGI3NGY0NDA5OWMzZGQwZWI0OTRiZjgwMTYxOWYyNTAyNjI2YTJjZjdkMTZmZCIsImp0aSI6IjFmN2IwODkxLTJkMGUtNDBhZS04MWJiLWQwODVjY2NhOGYyZSIsImlhdCI6MTY2NDI3Njk0NH0.6Q7CPtQIN0uB1ZbVQBj5dshqioop3dJKEpla5DQS5K5qtRPw38SxTEJ1f1DJ_Ka_sgMp_fdh9EEABipTgtgMqg'
And header uniqueid = 'ca38003e-0a8b-47b9-9ac5-4c327c05520f'
And header x-page = 'Home'
When url 'https://jiocinemaqa-api.jio.ril.com/user/v1/watchlist?groups=[["Movie"],["Show"]]'
When method GET
Then status 200
* print response
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this public API to test:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param groups = '[["Movie"],["Show"]]'
* method get
```

And you can verify in the response you see this:

```
"args": {
  "groups": "[[\"Movie\"],[\"Show\"]]"
},
```

And also:

```
"url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?groups=[[\"Movie\"]%2C[\"Show\"]]"
```

This proves that Karate is sending the right thing. Keep in mind that your server may have a bug.